# Why does Polygon binary image have different size at MySQL server and fetched result in app?

Tags: c#, mysql, binary, geospatial, fetch

I'm working with the geospatial native data in MySQL like: `Polygons, Points` etc..

I'm trying to fetch some data and there isn't any trouble with it.

But the size of data is different between data at MySQL server and the return object from that server into my application.

Here is proof:

http://s23.postimg.org/nsiyyq1kb/image.png (here you can see, that the size of object equals 177 bytes), but when I'm fetching this object, I've dumped at VS the next:

[image]

I coulnd't confuse with other object, just because there is only 1 record in table (I'm testing some MySQL features, so the data is so).

So the question is: "Why does MySQL server show me 177 and VS watch dialog 181?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've searched in web and analyzed, those 4 bytes are MySQL specific metadata, that help MySQL to determinate different binary object not just as simple `BLOB`, but a specific type for MySQL, like: Polygon, Point etc...

So those 4 bytes are internally used in MySQL for its internal type identification tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a random guess but 177+4 = 181, 4 extra bytes leads me to suspect a prefix or suffix integer specifying the length or something?

Is the first or last 4 bytes 0xb1 0x00 0x00 0x00?

Edit: Or could be some kind of checksum?

Comment: no, it's not, it seems to be smth metadata, that helpes define the object as not a simple BLOB object, but a specific one (Polygon, Point etc...)